# How can I use AND logic to check if cells A1 and A2 contain certain text, to return a value in cell C1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| DB | Result | Lookup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | Fail | dbname.abc True |

I'm trying this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FAIL",D2)),$B2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("True",E2)),$B2))
```

However, this only checking is one condition is met, I need both conditions to be met

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FAIL",D2)),$B2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("True",E2)),$B2))
```

Comment: In your example there's no need to use ISNUMBER/SEARCH. `=IF(AND(D2="Fail",E2="True"),$B2,"")`

Comment: @P.b I edited my example. I need the second condition to check if E2 contains the text "True"

Comment: `=IF(AND(D2="Fail",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("True",E2))),$B2,"")`

Comment: @P.b I get a blank cell. Could this be because my value in D2 is actually a formula?